# How to save and reload hidden states of Keras encoder-decoder model for inference

Tags: python-3.x, keras, nlp, lstm, seq2seq

I'm working on a sequence to sequence text generation using the encoder decoder architecture with LSTM layers in Keras. 
My code is a modified version of the Keras LSTM seq2seq tutorial: 
https://keras.io/examples/lstm_seq2seq/ 
After training the model, I want to set up an inference mode where I can decode a sequence using only the hidden states of the pretained model, without retraining the whole model each time.
I'm looking for a way to save these hidden LSTM states to a file and then reload them to set up my inference model.

A fraction of the model training part looks like this:

```
encoder = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)
```

I will later need the hidden cell states and encoder outputs (encoder_outputs, state_h and state_c) to set up the inference model (as in the tutorial) in the same way:

```
encoder_model = Model(inputs=encoder_inputs,outputs=[encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c])
```

Reusing the variables when having one program works fine, however I want to split my code into training and inference. I would then need to find a way to save the hidden cell states to a file.

What I've tried so far is

- saving state_h and state_c, which are Tensors, directly to file, but reshaping then from Tensor to a numpy array did not work for me
- saving the whole Keras model, loading it in inference mode and extracting the hidden cell states via

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
model.save("current_model.h5")
newmodel = load_model('./current_model.h5', custom_objects={'AttentionLayer': AttentionLayer})

encoder_outputs_2, state_h_2, state_c_2 = newmodel.layers[7].output
```

Reassigning the variables in that way did work, but not feeding them into inference model: that gave me the error message

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor     Tensor("input_1_2:0", shape=(?, 30), dtype=float32) at layer "input_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

Any help with what I've tried so far or ideas for new approaches would be appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue: the Graph disconnected error occurred due to referencing an incorrect instance of the stacked LSTM layers, should have been newmodel.layers[6].output